# Write to file and send AJAX response at once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**UPDATE:**

I used another solution to write my data into a file. It seems that I can't echo data while AJAX is waiting for a response. So I now use fwrite.

```
$fileHandle = '';
$fileHandle = fopen("export.txt","w");
fwrite($fileHandle, $export);
```

---

**Original:**

Hi there,
maybe my logic is wrong.
I make an AJAX call to get data from another URL.
That worked so far.

But now I want to add an file export also.

```
$handler = new MyHandler();
// Step 1: get data from URL
$dataAjax = $handler->getData($_POST['data']);
// Step 2: write the data into a text file to provide a download
$handler->writeToText($dataAjax);
echo json_encode($dataAjax);
```

Now the console shows me a "parserError" because my JSON data contains also the string I wanted to write into the file. That's bad and unwanted.
This below is just a test how I want to write my data into a txt file:

```
function writeToText($data)
{
   header("Content-type: text/plain");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.txt");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Expires: 0");
   $title = "";
   $title .= "Name,Quantity,Model,Price,Weight,Status"."\n";
   echo $title;
}
```

That is how the error looks like:

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "Name,Quantity,Model,Price,Weight,Status\n[{\"domain\":\"Text\",\"name\":\"Banana\}]",
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK"
} 
 parsererror
```

Comment: so what do you want the file to be downloaded as , `json` or `csv` because it looks like you are mixing both.

Comment: There is no mix. As you see the Content-type is text/plain and the string is just a list.
The parsererror is a Demonstration how the browser interpret the data it received. 
The browser receives JSON but the file shall write as plain text.

Comment: i see. one more thing i noticed was in your `writeToText` function you are accepting an argument `$data` but you are not processing it. is that code missing or did you forget to add that

Comment: No that is ok. As I've written that this function is a demonstration. I now send the data but for this example I've used a fix sample to test it.

Comment: can you paste the code for calling the ajax function?